# How can i copy clipboard from DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview, clipboard

I have winform project in c# that has DataGridView control name "dgv". Also there is a  DataTable name "dt_formula". These two controls work in an integrated way.

These control have same rows and columns count. `Dgv` keeps number result value and `dt_formula` keeps its formula. To more specific:

```
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "8"  // that keeps the result

dt_formula.Rows[0][0] "=5+3"// that keeps its formula.
```

I know how to copy clipboard from Datagridview SelectedCells.

```
private void copyToClipboard()
{
    DataObject dataObj = dgv.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
}
```

But I do not want this.

What I want is after selected cells when clicked copy I want to copy clipboard from `dt_formula` with the same selected rows and column index of dgv. I added pic explanation. Is there any solution for this?[image]

Comment: You are using dgv.GetClipboardContent() to get the content you want to add to the Clipboard. You should replace that line with a new Dataobject which contains the formula.

Comment: Since the `DataTable` `dt_formula` is obviously NOT bound to the grid and assuming that the `DataTable` `dt_formula` reflects an exact cell to cell mapping, then I would guess that using the grids `SelectedCells` collection may help in identifying “which” cells in the `dt_formula` table to copy. Each `DataGridViewCell` in the grids `SelectedCells` collection would have a row and column index. I am not sure if I want to know how the `string` value “=5+3” in the `dt_formula` table is translated to an “8” in the `DataGridView.`